# How to send scheduled message via HTTP POST?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

In FB Console, I can schedule the message to be sent at later time.

Is this possible to do with HTTP POST from my server?

Something like this:

```
 {
  "to" : "/topics/news",
  "at": "2016-01-13T14:55",
  "data" : {
    "message": "sync"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of the moment, no such parameter exists that can be used to set when a Push Notification will be sent. It is only available when using the Firebase Console or if you implement the time delay via your own App Server.